# How to extract a list statisitic from a list of lists in R?

Tags: r, list, loops, regression, vegan

A data set

```
set.seed(111)
library(vegan)
library(truncnorm)
df <- data.frame(sp1 = rep(rtruncnorm(10, a=0, b=1, mean = 0.50, sd = 0.2), times = 10),
                  sp2 = rep(rtruncnorm(10, a=0, b=1, mean = 0.70, sd = 0.1), times = 10),
                  env1 = rep(rtruncnorm(10, a=0, b=1, mean = 0.45, sd = 0.6), times = 10),
                  env2 = rep(rtruncnorm(10, a=0, b=1, mean = 0.65, sd = 0.6), times = 10)
                  )
```

Using this data, I calculate a test `rda` that is stored in `test`: which is a list of lists.

```
spe.rda  <- rda(df[,c(1:2)] ~ ., data = df[,c(3:4)]) 

test <- ordiR2step(rda(df[,c(1:2)]~1, data=df[,c(3:4)]), 
scope = formula(spe.rda), direction= "forward", R2scope=TRUE, pstep=1000)
```

I want to extract R2 from `test` to store the following in a dataframe with two columns as such. How can I do this? I can't spot the statistic when I open each of the lists but it does appear on the console.

```
variables      R2.adjusted
+ env1           0.08636035
<All variables>  0.08220187
+ env2           0.00842866
<none>           0.00000000
```

Comment: Can you share what `test` looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not super familiar with this package, but from inspecting the source code it looks like the output that's printed is never returned - try looking at `ordiR2step` in the console. You could try creating your own version that also returns it?

One generic workaround would be to use `capture.output` to save the printed stuff as a variable:

```r
r2_text = capture.output(test <- ordiR2step(rda(df[,c(1:2)]~1, data=df[,c(3:4)]), 
                                  scope = formula(spe.rda), direction= "forward",
                                  R2scope=TRUE, pstep=1000))
```

The `r2_text` object looks like this:

```r
[1] "Step: R2.adj= 0 "            "Call: df[, c(1:2)] ~ 1 "    
[3] " "                           "                R2.adjusted"
[5] "+ env1           0.08636035" "<All variables>  0.08220187"
[7] "+ env2           0.00842866" "<none>           0.00000000"
[9] ""
```

The saved output would need tidied up to get it into a data frame but it should be doable.